# Url Rewriting issue with plain text

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm having a little issue, i've placed these rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?s=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
```

and it works as long as the Link looks something like `search/test` `search/test/4` `search/test/`, the problem occurs, when i try to do something like this `search/test1 test2`. I guess i have to convert the searchstring into something that can be passed as url like `search/test1%20%test2`. Sadly i don't know how i could achieve this within .htaccess, so if anyone could provide me with some info that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the whitespace-character `\s` into your rule :

```
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)?$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?s=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
```

So, browsing to `search/test1 test2` will redirects to `search.php?s=test1 test2`.

```
var_dump($_GET) ; // array(1) { ["s"]=> string(11) "test1 test2" }
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i will accept it as answer as soon as the 'cooldown' is over! Maybe you can answer me another question real quick: I just noticed something strange (those above are the only rules i have in my .htaccess and my search.php does nothing at the moment, but when i try to navigate to `localhost/folder/search/no` it gives me an access forbidden error and redirects me to `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/folder/index.php?s=no`. It works with every other search term i tried so far, only for the no this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @SupaDupa Thank you. I work on LAMP, and this behavior is suprising. My tests on local doesn't make the same thing. Your folder `folder` exists? Does the `MultiViews` Apache option is activated?

Comment: yes, it exists, as i said it works with other terms as searchquery. And i'm not sure what you mean by MultiViews, could you elaborate on this one a little bit further? (sorry for being such a newb..)

Comment: @SupaDupa I'm sorry, I don't know what's happen. For multiview, I mean the Apache option `MultiViews` that could made some redirects if it find that something looks like at the query on the filesystem, but I'm not sure. Also, maybe have a look to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. Really sorry that I can't helps you more.